# Mapping Two Different Objects dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

Object1:

```
{
  "UserId": 123,
  "Name": "testuser",
  "Roles": [
    {
      "UserRole": "Admin"
    },
    {
      "UserRole": "NonAdmin"
    }
  ]
}
```

Object2:

```
{
  "Id": 123,
  "EmpName": "testuser",
  "UserRoles": [
    {
      "EmpRole": "Admin"
    },
    {
      "EmpRole": "NonAdmin"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to map this object in C# using automapper. It is working fine but we need to map this object dynamically without using C# code, like keep this properties in Json file or database. Is there any other approach? We need to avoid code changes in C# if any new property is added or removed in any object, so we are looking to convert object1 to Object2 dynamically without code change.

Comment: Store the source and target keys in a table?

Comment: Use a json parser library in c#.

Comment: Any one please provide solution for this Or suggest any approach I tried with reflection but issue with modify nested objects properties name